# Having problems with a Gambling Application on my website (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, get

I'm trying to make a section of my website to support gambling (with game money, not irl)

Goal: Create a simple Buy Ticket, Wait for tickets to be all gone, randomly select winner. So the end user can buy any amount of tickets left up to the total of 8 available tickets and then the script will choose a winner out of the number of applicants that bought a ticket.

Current Issue: My main issue is having problems with PHP storing and retrieving data.

```
<form action="games.php" method"post" name="add_tickets">
<ul>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="one"><br>
<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="two"><br>
<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="three"><br>
<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="four"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

So I'm using Radio buttons for this. When a button is selected and submitted, it will post the data over to games.php.

Then on games.php I'll have my script do its job and when its finished it will redirect the user back to index.php where the form was and have the user's name ($username) beside the radio button he selected.

Here is games.php code: NOTE: this isn't all the code... just a snippet on where my main issue is

```
if(isset($_POST['add_tickets'])){
$ticket = $_POST['one'];
$ticket = $_POST['two'];
$ticket = $_POST['three'];
$ticket = $_POST['four'];
}

$ticket_owners[] = "$ticket";
print_r($ticket_owners);
```

I'm trying to input which ticket they bought and  their username into an array which then i'll run rand(array) to select a winner and return the answer.

Hmm, did I explain this okay? probably not... I wish I knew a little bit more about PHP... sigh

Can anyone shed some light on this... is this the wrong direction to take? Can it be done better with different methods?

Comment: Can you explain the problem here?

Comment: Trying to get the data that was posted from the form into an array which associates  the username with a ticket #.
array = array($ticketone => $username) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should have been

```
$ticket = $_POST['ticket']; // this will contain "one", "two", "three", or "four"
```

remove

```
if(isset($_POST['add_tickets'])){
}
```

and remove

```
$ticket_owners[] = "$ticket";
```

Now as to storing the username in a list that you will later use to select a random winner from... You will need something of a database or cache. As your array for example will cease to exist once the page is rendered and served to the user.

Comment: when i echo back $ticket; i get nothing but a notice, 
Notice: Undefined index: ticket in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\games.php on line 10

Comment: what is on line 10? is it `$ticket = $_POST['ticket'];` ? In that case you haven't sent the form yet. Go back to index.php, refresh, select a radio button and hit submit. If there is something else on line 10, please state what it is.

Comment: edit: nevermind... method="post" was method"post"... missing the equals sign

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since your inputs look like this `<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="x">`, you need to check `$_POST['ticket']` and it will have on of the following values: none (variable won't exist) / one / two / three / four.

Where are you saving who bought what ticket? Where are you storing/receiving data, if you want help with that, please post code and elaborate in what you want to achieve and how you already tried

Comment: It would be stored in MYSQL and possibly some data stored in their session